# Windows new profile loading over 1 minute

Tags: windows, powershell

Im using windows10 Enterprise template on vcenter and im creating users on vm using this powershell script:

I have a powershell script that creates new users on new vm that has windows10 Enterprise,
This is the script:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$pass,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$user,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
    [string]$gr
)
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pass -Force
New-LocalUser $user -Password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $gr -Member $user
```

If i create new user through admin user the new user profile loads in 20 sec

Is there a way to speed up user profile first log in using this script?
Thanks

Comment: In order to speed it up, you first need to [diagnose why its slow](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/slow-boot-slow-logon-sbsl-a-tool-called-xperf-and-links-you-need/ba-p/255618)

Comment: Its always a fresh install from template. and also if i create  a new user using administrator user the user login is 20 sec but if i use this script it takes up to 1 min so i dont know what is making this slower @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Right, but in order to find out what's taking up all this time, you need to _measure_ what's going on during logon (by using `xperf` for example).

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty normal for windows. `New-LocalUser` does not create the profile, (home directory, user settings, registry, etc.) so you need an additional step to get windows to complete the first-time setup.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/946885/411612) about using the windows [CreateProfile API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createprofile) to create a user-profile on-demand is probably what you're looking for.

---

A simpler way is to just do part of the profile creation ahead of time by starting a process as that user. This skips processing some desktop items like Theme setup, but may speed up the profile creation enough for what you need:

```
Start-Process notepad -Credential $myUserCreds
```

And when using templates, Microsoft also recommends [customizing the Default user profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/customize-default-local-user-profile) to speed up new user profile creation. This lets windows just copy most things from the default profile rather than generate entirely new settings. It should be done as you sysprep your VM for templating:

> Create an Unattend.xml file that contains the Copy Profile parameter (`Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup\CopyProfile`). By using this Copy Profile parameter, the settings of the user who is currently logged on are copied to the default user profile.
>
> Example sysprep command:
>
> ```
> %systemroot%\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe /oobe /shutdown /generalize /unattend:c:\answerfile\unattend.xml
> ```

Comment: Hello, i did add the `Start-Process` and i do see the proc in the task manager but it did not lessen the login time, working on creating a profile \ running the load profile function for PowerShell  - there is not much examples there so it is difficult for me.  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/userenv/nf-userenv-createprofile)

Comment: @gsr have you tried following the script in the linked answer? Using the api in powershell has already been done: https://serverfault.com/a/946885/411612 Also consider the linked PS module that wraps this: https://gist.github.com/crshnbrn66/7e81bf20408c05ddb2b4fdf4498477d8#file-user-profile-psm1-L121